# Pass data from one function to three listviews on different forms vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, listview

I have a function in a module to get data from my database file. It is working fine when I used it to get data for form1. It is possible the same function can be used to get data on form2.listview2 and form3.listview3?
I want to the use same function to get data from the database on these three forms' listview.

Shall be thankful, sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Yes it is possible. You have provided a specific problem for us to help with though. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn what is expected of a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  strSQL = "Select DEALERID, SHOPNAME, DEALERNAME, CELLNUMBER, ADDRESS, DATED From TableDealerInformation"
        SQLiteCommand.CommandText = strSQL
        SQLiteCommand.Connection = SQLiteConnection
        SQLiteDataReader = SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader
        FormADDDEALER.ListViewAddDealer.Items.Clear()
        While (SQLiteDataReader.Read())
            With FormADDDEALER.ListViewAddDealer.Items.Add(SQLiteDataReader("DEALERID"))
                .SubItems.Add(SQLiteDataReader("SHOPNAME"))
                .SubItems.Add(SQLiteDataReader("DEALERNAME"))
                .SubItems.Add(SQLiteDataReader("CELLNUMBER"))
                .SubItems.Add(SQLiteDataReader("ADDRESS"))
                .SubItems.Add(SQLiteDataReader("DATED"))
            End With
        End While
```

This code is written in a Function, currently it is working fine to show data on form FormADDDEALER and in list ListViewAddDealer.

But I want the same information on Form2 in listview2 and Form3 in listview 3. It is possible that the same function can be used on Form2 and Form3 ?